# ASP MVC Bootstrap Navigation Dropdowns: Hover on Large Screen, Click on Small

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am using the standard Bootstrap class="nav navbar-nav" for navigation with dropdown menus:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li role="presentation" class="@Html.IsSelected("Appointments", "selected")">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="/Content/images/nav_appts.png" style="padding: 0px 5px 3px 0px;">Appointments<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointments Page 1", "Index", "Appointments")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointments Page 2", "Page2", "Appointments")</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    // more menu items
</ul>
```

Out of the box, the dropdowns only appear if you click on them.  I found a way to make them appear if you hover.  In the css:

```
/* causes the dropdowns to be displayed on-hover instead of on-click */
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block; 
}
```

This works great on a standard large screen.  But once the screen becomes tablet size, the navigation then switches to the box with bars that drops down to show the nav. Once we get here, I DO NOT want the sub-menu items to appear on hover.  I understand that on most tablets, the concept of 'hover' doesn't exist, as there is no mouse.  None the less, in case someone is using the site with a very small laptop (etc etc) I want to be able to control this.  I tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: inline; 
     }
}
```

And I played around with a few other options, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Have you tried `@media screen and (min-width: 830px) { ...display:block`?

Comment: display:block is what's making it appear on hover.  I want the opposite of that.

Comment: So if you add `min-width` to the `block` rule and use `max-width` with the `inline` rule, doesn't that give you what you need?

Comment: ah ok ok... lemme try that

Comment: Bingo!  If you add an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two rules with different width so each applies depending on screen size:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 831px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block; 
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: inline; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, for some reason, if I give the element any kind of display at all, inline OR block, it shows on hover.  So the solution ended up being to keep the first @media, and not use the second.  Thank you!